# convert 3d to 2d - graph plotting using javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, graph, plot

I have some 3dimensional data(X,Y,Z)
This is actually the position of on object on a given track.

I want to convert this data into a 2d graph.
This needs to be on the website, were the x,y,z is dynamic.. i am getting the values using ajax.

But the challenge is how do i convert it to 2d graph?

Comment: Depends on what will the Z represent in a 2d graph. otherwise - just get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like Highcharts - i believe it's just what you want.

> http://www.highcharts.com/demo/

This will allow you to create a chart using JSON encoded values.

Answer (score 0):

I known some framework for make JS chart

Some are free or evaluation.

Ext JS:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/#sample-3

Google chart:
http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/chart/

FusionChart:
http://www.fusioncharts.com/

I hope this helps :)